# UDP Client/Server object transfer help

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I'm trying to transfer an ArrayList from a client to a server using the UDP protocol.

The transfer starts at the "max" if statement.
Same in the server side

This is the client:

```
public class UdpClient {
protected DatagramPacket sendPacket;
protected DatagramPacket receivePacket;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    UdpClient upd = new UdpClient();
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput oo = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
    ByteArrayInputStream baos;
    ObjectInputStream oos;
    System.out
            .println("Commands: Time, Date, Weather, Sum-number, Max-number, Exit");
    while (true) {
        String fromUsr = inFromUser.readLine();
        if (fromUsr.equals("bye")) {
            break;
        } else if (fromUsr.equals("weather")) {
            sendData = fromUsr.getBytes();
            upd.sendPacket(sendData, clientSocket);
            System.out
                    .println("Please select a ctiy: Lund, Malmo, Stockholm");
            String weather = inFromUser.readLine();
            sendData = weather.getBytes();
            upd.sendPacket(sendData, clientSocket);
            upd.receivePacket(clientSocket, receiveData);
        } else if (fromUsr.equals("max")) {
            sendData = fromUsr.getBytes();
            upd.sendPacket(sendData, clientSocket);
            String max = inFromUser.readLine().trim();
            upd.nums(max, arr);
            oo.writeObject(arr);
            byte[] buf = new byte[bStream.toByteArray().length];
            buf = bStream.toByteArray();
            upd.sendPacket(buf, clientSocket);
            System.out.println(arr);
        } else {
            // send data that of the user
            sendData = fromUsr.getBytes();
            upd.sendPacket(sendData, clientSocket);
            upd.receivePacket(clientSocket, receiveData);
        }
        String fromServer = new String(upd.getData());
        System.out.println("Message from server:\n" + fromServer);
    }
}

private void sendPacket(byte[] sendData, DatagramSocket clientSocket)
        throws IOException {
    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("ericman-PC");
    sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress,
            9876);
    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

}

private void receivePacket(DatagramSocket serverSocket, byte[] receiveData)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] rData = new byte[1024];
    receiveData = rData;
    receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
}
```

This is the Server

```
    public class UdpServer {
protected DatagramPacket receivePacket;
protected DatagramPacket sendPacket;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    UdpServer upd = new UdpServer();
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
    DateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    DateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    ByteArrayInputStream baos;
    ObjectInputStream oos;
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("****************************************"
                + "\nServer is connected");
        upd.receivePacket(serverSocket, receiveData);
        String str = new String(upd.getData()).trim();
        System.out.println("Message received is:" + " " + str);
        if (str.equals("time")) {
            str = currentTime.format(date);
            sendData = str.getBytes();
            upd.sendPacket(serverSocket, sendData);
        } else if (str.equals("date")) {
            str = currentDate.format(date);
            sendData = str.getBytes();
            upd.sendPacket(serverSocket, sendData);
        } else if (str.equals("weather")) {
            upd.receivePacket(serverSocket, receiveData);
            str = upd.weather(str = new String(upd.getData()).trim());
            sendData = str.getBytes();
            upd.sendPacket(serverSocket, sendData);

        } else if (str.equals("max")) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            System.out.println("waitng for object to come");
            upd.receivePacket(serverSocket, buf);
            baos = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
            oos = new ObjectInputStream(baos);
            Object o = oos.readObject();
            System.out.println(o);
        } else {
            str = "Unknown command, please try again..";
            sendData = str.getBytes();
            upd.sendPacket(serverSocket, sendData);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the error i get in the Server side

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at UdpServer.main(UdpServer.java:54)
```

Line 54 that the error indicates is this line on the server

```
baos = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
            oos = new ObjectInputStream(baos);
```

If you could help me out of why this error is happening? thanx!

Comment: If your data can easily be more than 1024 bytes, reading the first 1024 bytes will be be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates alot of arrays it immediately discards.  I would use a debugger to step through the code so you understand what it is doing.

```
private void receivePacket(DatagramSocket serverSocket, byte[] receiveData)
        throws IOException {
    // create a new array
    byte[] rData = new byte[1024];
    // throw away the orignal array so the new array will be update.
    receiveData = rData;
    // copy into the new array, not the old one.
    receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
}
```

In this case, the original `receiveData` will not me modified so it will contain lots of `0` bytes.

---

```
        byte[] buf = new byte[bStream.toByteArray().length];
        buf = bStream.toByteArray();
```

This creates three arrays when all you need is one.  The first array `bStream.toByteArray()` is created just so you can determine what length it would be.  You create a second array which is the same length but empty and put it in `buf`  Finally you discard the second array and replace it with a copy of the first array.

Comment: `private void receivePacket(DatagramSocket serverSocket, byte[] receiveData)
        throws IOException {
    // create a new array
    byte[] rData = new byte[1024];
    // throw away the orignal array so the new array will be update.
    receiveData = rData;
    // copy into the new array, not the old one.
    receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
}`

Comment: I did it like that coz if i used the the method again and again, it used to keep part of the previous received bytes. Would you suggest some other away, to make a method to receive bytes so It always stays empty so it does not contain the previous bytes?

Comment: Why does containing the previous bytes matter?  Java is pass-by-value so you cannot change the callers reference.

Comment: If for example in the first command i ask for the time, server sends me the time, then if i ask for example for the weather, that byte still contains some digits of the time, depending on how big is the weather information, which in my case is just sunny. That is what i did that, so every time i receive something from the server my buffer is empty. So if i did not do that, i get printed info from my previous request